# iphone Google Calendar Events

Tags: iphone

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now and have read a bunch on the google apis.

In short, I'm trying to build an Iphone app that basically shows my google public calendar but most importantly get the events and do some stuff with them. <-- possibly a different question later.

I am missing something simple. I have created an api key and associated that with my iOS bundle ID. I have not, however, created the OAUTH stuff on the premise :'Use API keys to identify your project when you do not need to access user data'

I dont need the users data, just MY events data. am i correct in this?

I have gotten the gData lib to work and download the events however, i have to enter my email and password in code which is not acceptable. I *have* seen code where developers are putting their usernames and password in client code. Is that right?

With the my API key i do this @"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?maxResults=10&key=xxxxxxxx";

and get this:

```
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Do i HAVE to use oauth? Where should i go from here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found that i must use an oAuth token. this page has been most useful to me 
http://cornempire.net/2012/01/15/part-3-oauth2-and-configuring-your-application-with-google/

And i believe is the best way of handling authentication if i HAVE to use oAuth. Though I'm not sure why if i tie my API key to my iOS bundle ID.